# Node-red looping on start raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

I was using node-red in my raspberry pi normally until get the brillant idea to install new nodes.
Now, I am unable to start it. The node-red is in loop when starting.

```
>    Start Node-RED   Once Node-RED has started, point a browser at
> http://192.168.0.113:1880 On Pi Node-RED works better with the Firefox
> or Chrome browser   Use   node-red-stop                          to
> stop Node-RED Use   node-red-start                         to start
> Node-RED again Use   node-red-log                           to view
> the recent log output Use   sudo systemctl enable nodered.service  to
> autostart Node-RED at every boot Use   sudo systemctl disable
> nodered.service to disable autostart on boot   To find more nodes and
> example flows - go to http://flows.nodered.org   Starting as a systemd
> service. Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.. 10 Jan
> 00:29:50 - [info] Welcome to Node-RED
> =================== 10 Jan 00:29:50 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.17.5 10 Jan 00:29:50 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.12.3 10 Jan 00:29:50 -
> [info] Linux 4.9.35-v7+ arm LE 10 Jan 00:29:51 - [info] Loading
> palette nodes [../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c:165] error: cannot
> open device default node: pcm_params.c:2286: snd_pcm_hw_refine:
> Assertion `pcm && params' failed. nodered.service: main process
> exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT Unit nodered.service entered failed
> state. nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart. Stopping
> Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.... Starting Node-RED graphical
> event wiring tool.... Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool..
> 10 Jan 00:29:57 - [info] Welcome to Node-RED
> =================== 10 Jan 00:29:57 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.17.5 10 Jan 00:29:57 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.12.3 10 Jan 00:29:57 -
> [info] Linux 4.9.35-v7+ arm LE 10 Jan 00:29:58 - [info] Loading
> palette nodes [../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c:165] error: cannot
> open device default node: pcm_params.c:2286: snd_pcm_hw_refine:
> Assertion `pcm && params' failed. nodered.service: main process
> exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT Unit nodered.service entered failed
> state. nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart. Stopping
> Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.... Starting Node-RED graphical
> event wiring tool.... Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool..
> 10 Jan 00:30:04 - [info] Welcome to Node-RED
> =================== 10 Jan 00:30:04 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.17.5 10 Jan 00:30:04 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.12.3 10 Jan 00:30:04 -
> [info] Linux 4.9.35-v7+ arm LE 10 Jan 00:30:05 - [info] Loading
> palette nodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the directory `/home/pi/.node-red` and open the `package.json` file.

It should contain a dependencies section that lists the extra nodes you installed (assuming you did so via the Palette Manager in the editor). Identify any nodes related to playing audio - the crashing error is related to trying to use the mpg123 command line tool for playing audio files.

Then on the command line, run `npm remove NAME-OF-MODULE --save`.

Node-RED should then restart cleanly.